# Karate Ignore scenarios depending on the environment

Tags: karate

Is possible to ignore some scenarios depending of the enviroment in an elegant way?
I have a lot of differents scenarios (tens)  and check almost all scenarios, but some enviroments must skips some concrete scenarios.

Thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

That is what "tags" are for. Please refer to the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#cucumber-tags